# A fantasy series with an ancient wizard and a chess-like game

Tags: story-identification, wizards

The main character was a wizard from an ancient empire that had some kind of soul stone placed in his tomb and took over the body of a female tomb robber.

I remember some kind of chess analog that the main character would teach others and one of the pieces could make other pieces stronger by "forging them" (I think it was called) and a recurring motif in the series was that all the adversity the character in the books faced was the gods forging them in a cosmic version of the game.

Answer (score 4):

Mage series by Jim Farris.

The chess analogue was called chatto
The main character is Eddas Ayar.

- Book 1 - Mage
- Book 2 - Raven of Yorindar
- Book 3 - Arc of Time
- Book 4 - The Wench of Woe
- Book 5 - The Mountain, The Raven and the Sea
- Book 6 - The game of the gods

Comment: Oh, my.. I was going to edit this with links to the author's page on these books... But WOW, are they bad!  [Visit at your own risk](http://xaa.tripod.com/magepromo.htm)

Comment: They aint that bad, ive read a lot worse. The promo doesnt do the books any favours though

Comment: I think @K-H-W was referring to the website, and it is, indeed, wow.

Comment: Organic marble is right; it's the website I was referring to, and its really bad for this day and age.

Comment: @K-H-W - It's really bad for the mid 90's as well.